# What book features dragons, song-driven magic, and talking otters?

Tags: story-identification, magic

Read these books when I was a youth and loved them.  I haven't been able to remember what they were at all for years.
The details I do remember are this:
They had talking Otters who raised the main character (a young boy).
The dragons were lost or nearly extinct and the young boy had to bring them back.
In order to do their magic they had to sing or play music.

Every search I do on Google for these criteria just get me the books by Christopher Paolini about Dragons and those are not what I want.

Comment: When (what year or thereabout) were you a youth? If you know, were the books new then? And were they marketed as children's books, young adult, adult?

Comment: They were young adult I believe, I was a youth in the late 80's to mid 90's and I have no idea if they were new or not back then.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[NightPool](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060243619), by Shirley Rousseau Murphy and published in 1985 by Harper & Row, first book of the [Dragonbards](https://www.goodreads.com/series/53209-dragonbards) series.

> Injured in battle with the Dark Raiders, sixteen-year-old Tebriel is healed by a colony of talking otters and sets out to fight the Dark and its forces of evil in the world of Tirror.

Comment: SWEET!!!!!  That's it!!

Comment: @Pselus You're welcome!  Or, i r a l33t googlez hackorz ;)

Answer (score 12):

[Spellsinger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellsinger) series, by Alan Dean Foster.

Comment: Nope, but might be worth a read!  Thanks!

Comment: When I heard talking otters and song-based music, this was my first thought too!  I don't think this series has dragons or a boy hero however.

Comment: It does have at least one dragon, Falameezar, in the very first book. That said, the talking otters definitely do not raise Jon-Tom, although I think Mudge does mentor his son.