# Book About An Otter set in medieval times?

Tags: story-identification, novel, animals, medieval

Does anyone remember a book that featured an otter. It was set in medieval times and all the characters were animals and he had to save the kingdom. And I just can't remember the name. Please help!

Comment: Not the [Redwall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redwall) series?

Comment: These are pretty sparse details - do you have anything more you can remember about it? Cover art? When you read it?

Comment: @Ben - lack of details aside - you should post an answer (I think you're correct)

Comment: @HorusKol - Can there really be that many books about otters in the medieval era?  :)

Comment: @WadCheber to test that thought I googled ["book fiction otter medieval"](https://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=i8wLU5rIF6yN8Qfd5oGgAg&gws_rd=cr#q=book+fiction+otter+medieval)... second result

Comment: @HorusKol - I'm not surprised. After all, they're otters, not [guinea pigs](http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1212865/images/o-GUINEA-PIG-ARMOR-facebook.jpg).

Comment: @WadCheber [well...](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ihdCvxD1gFw/T-ih-A1me5I/AAAAAAAABiY/_Q2MWAb1FEI/s1600/Armour+otter.jpg)

Comment: If it included humans/humanoid creatures, I would have suggested Niel Hancock's [Circle of Light](http://www.goodreads.com/series/49109-circle-of-light) series (starting with Greyfax Grimwald).

Answer (score 5):

From my knowledge, this sounds a lot like the [Redwall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redwall) series, by Brian Jaques.

This series is about a group of anthropomorphic woodland animals living in an Abbey called Redwall, one of the more prevalent characters through the series is Martin, the warrior-mouse (he and his fathers before him have several books devoted to their adventures alone). These creatures are often under attack by "vermin" (depicted as rats, weasels, lizards and the like), but (fortunately for Redwall) these are often deterred by the Badgers that safeguard the coast in Salamandastron; a mountain fortress overlooking the sea.

As for Otters, there are a few in the series (that have their own tales*), such as

- [Deyna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Redwall_characters#Deyna) was kidnapped while still very young, and raised by vermin, but later runs away to find the rest of his family at Redwall
- [Mhera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Redwall_characters#Mhera) later becomes the new Abbess of Redwall, after she is reunited with her long lost brother (Deyna)
- [Ruffgar Brookback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Redwall_characters#Ruffgar_Brookback) joins a pair of Badgers in their quest to liberate Salamandastron
- [Shogg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Redwall_characters#Shogg) who, along with a few other characters, escape slavery and set forth to find Redwall Abbey
- [Bragoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Redwall_characters#Bragoon_and_Saro) grew up in Redwall, then set out to venture the surrounding lands
- [Tiria Wildlough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Redwall_characters#Tiria_Wildlough) is visited by Martin the Warrior in a dream and given the task of liberating the otterclans of Green Isle

as well as a few others.

---

<sub>*badum-tss</sub>

Comment: How could you omit the High Rhulain?!

Comment: @randal'thor *"as well as a few others"*. I didn't want to give away some of the better ones ;)

Answer (score 5):

This sounds a bit like [Alan Dean Foster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Dean_Foster)'s [*Spellsinger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellsinger) series, in which the anthropomorphic otter, Mudge, plays main friend and ally to the human protagonist. The series is notable for its anthropomorphized animal characters, and for its otherwise Western Medieval Fantasy characters being awash in substance use and abuse.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the book is [Nightpool](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060243619) by Shirley Rousseau Murphy?  Apparently it is about a teenager who teams up with talking otters to "fight the Dark".  I was looking up something else in Stack Exchange and found a similar request to what you're looking for at this question: [What book features dragons, song-driven magic, and talking otters?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/what-book-features-dragons-song-driven-magic-and-talking-otters/2116#2116)